# Torque: Bad UID for job execution MSG

Tags: linux, job-scheduling, torque

I've installed Torque using this [guide](https://jabriffa.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/installing-torquepbs-job-scheduler-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/).

The author said that for `submit_hosts` one should use SERVER (short name) instead of SERVER@DOMAIN (FQDN). But that didn't help me. How can I solve this problem?

my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Clusterlab.local Clusterlab

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.1.1 Clusterlab
192.168.1.2 Node1lab
192.168.1.3 Node2lab
```

my server settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of causes for this error message. However, submitting from the server is an exception, and should always be allowed, regardless of configurations. Also, `acl_hosts` doesn't matter unless you've set `acl_host_enable=True` in `qmgr`.

The fact that you have Cluster resolving to both 127.0.0.1 AND 192.168.1.1 is incorrect. You should comment out the resolution to the loopback address.

If those don't help, one other quick thing you can try is to create `/etc/hosts.equiv`, and add a single line to it, with a lone +. (Be aware that this is considered insecure, which may or may not matter to you, depending on who can gain access to the nodes; but it's a way to troubleshoot the issue and get more information, at the very least.)